# Make Custom Label lowercase

Tags: visualforce, customlabel

Is it possible to format at custom label referenced in Visualforce, specifically make the label all lowercase?

For example if I have a custom label called "Opportunity" with a value of "Opportunity" could I reference it in VF as:

```
{!$Label.Opportunity} <!-- make this "opportunity" not "Opportunity" -->
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **LOWER(text, [locale])**  function to this .

```
{!LOWER($Label.Opportunity)}
```

In case you are interested in more functions like this ,refer this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

Answer (score 5):

See [Visualforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm). You can use the `LOWER` function:

```
{!LOWER(someValue)}
```